# What to do about historical Wikipedia articles contradicting each other in different languages?

Tags: world-war-two, hungary

There are several examples where two versions of the same Wikipedia page in different languages contradict each other. One concrete historical example, is this recount of how two Soviet emissaries died before the siege of Budapest, found at the bottom of [this section in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Budapest#Encirclement_of_Budapest) and here in [Hungarian](https://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budapest_ostroma#Ultim%C3%A1tum_a_n%C3%A9met_parancsnoks%C3%A1gnak). (I recall that the official Hungarian version changed after 1990 due to the changed political climate, apparently the English page is still the original version.) Is this normal, or can something be done about it? I am interested in general advice, and also in how to resolve this one particular instance.

Comment: As stated, this is a question for Wikipedia policy; historical sources and methods will not be helpful. Could you revise the question to isolate what you want to know?

Comment: If you're asking which version to believe, chase down the references.

Comment: OK, I've closed the question, and asked another one only about this historical instance: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/70980/what-happened-to-the-soviet-emissaries-at-the-siege-of-budapest

Comment: In general, nothing can be done besides being vigilant in multiple languages. Inaccuracies abound, and without admin intervention those with particular agendas will continue to find Wikipedia a home to their ideas.

Answer (score 4):

**Correcting conflicting claims**

It's normal, and something can be done about it. In each individual article, add material with verifiable, authoritative sources from the literature about that article's topic, and/or correct existing material based on the sources. If a change you make is reverted or challenged, discuss it on the talk page.

The key thing to note is that contradictions between Wikipedia articles are not evidence that either article should change. The reason for this is that Wikipedia is not a reliable source—according to [Wikipedia's own standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reliable_sources#User-generated_content). If you are working on article B, and article A contradicts something in article B, it doesn't matter, because Wikipedia's article on A is not a reliable source for B.

If the sources for topics A and B contradict each other, then their Wikipedia articles should contradict each other, too, because Wikipedia's job is to reflect the existing literature, not correct it.

*Mutatis mutandis* for articles about topic A in different languages.

**Judging conflicting claims**

If you are only trying to determine which of the two competing claims is true, then you must check the sources cited (and possibly other literature, of course) and judge for yourself. [Wikipedia policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Verifiability) requires that all factual claims have sources indicated in the article. These are shown by numbers in brackets, which link to full academic citations at the bottom of the article. Wikipedia is not always reliable about information about a topic, but it's a great entry point into the literature about nearly any topic.

Comment: The answer is good but I recommend discussing important changes in discussion page of the articles BEFORE making the changes. Being bold while editing on topics where even sources conflict and some people may have strong feelings about is quite likely a recipe for disaster. Additionally, that different articles have contradicting factual sentences is a problem in itself because at least one of them is wrong or doesn't contain all the relevant versions of sources.