# What happened to the Soviet emissaries at the siege of Budapest?

Tags: world-war-two, hungary

Before the siege of Budapest, the Soviets sent two emissaries to the German to offer them a chance to surrender. According to one version of the story (recounted on the English Wikipedia, see the [end of the section here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Budapest#Encirclement_of_Budapest)) they were killed by the Germans, while according to another version, they died by accidentally running on a mine, and by Soviet friendly fire, respectively ([recounted on the Hungarian Wikipedia](https://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budapest_ostroma#Ultim%C3%A1tum_a_n%C3%A9met_parancsnoks%C3%A1gnak)). Understandably, before 1990, in Hungary the first version was the official one, and after 1990 the second. However, the English Wikipedia still states the first version, so I'm curious whether there has been new historical insights missed by foreign sources, or just current politics prefers the new version. (Although then probably another revision is required soon.)

Comment: To add to the confusion the Russian Wikipedia entry states that one of the emissaries was killed by Hungarian mortar shelling.

Comment: The event is obscure enough that it probably hasn't received much attention by historians outside Hungary and the USSR/Russia. So, you'll probably have to live with that. The English wikipedia cites 3 Russian/Soviet sources for the event (and no Hungarian ones), BTW.

Comment: Well, at least I've added a note about the uncertainty to Wikipedia, I don't see what else could be done.

Answer (score 2):

According o the version of Earl Ziemke, which of course is only another one but interestingly managed to catch up with all the versions you gave, here is what happened:

- The Soviets emitted through speakers, asking for surrender
- Then on the 29th at 9 am they announced emissaries would enter Axis' perimeter
- One of the two emissary captains was "killed in the no man's land": I guess it is the story of the mine
- The other was able to reach the German commander, who refused to receive him, and then, going back, he was killed by an Hungarian barrage, apparently from artillery